# How to assign numeric values to new column based on numeric values of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this really simple task I need to do, but I can't seem to be able to solve it in any efficient way.
I'm supposed to calculate the number of different periods for separate individuals from a large data frame.

Here's an example of my data:

```
myData <- tibble(
  individuals = c(rep("r1",9),rep("r2",9), rep("r3",9)),
  group = c(rep(324,3), rep(326,3), rep(328,3), rep(330,3), rep (332,3), rep(334,3), rep(336,3), rep(338,3), rep(340,3)))

individuals group
   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 r1            324
 2 r1            324
 3 r1            324
 4 r1            326
 5 r1            326
 6 r1            326
 7 r1            328
 8 r1            328
 9 r1            328
10 r2            330
# ... with 17 more rows
```

Now I want to create another column, where the first mentioned group of the individual gets 1, the other one 2, the third one 3 and then start the count again for the next individual. The desired outcome would be like this:

```
  individuals group period_number
   <chr>       <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 r1            324             1
 2 r1            324             1
 3 r1            324             1
 4 r1            326             2
 5 r1            326             2
 6 r1            326             2
 7 r1            328             3
 8 r1            328             3
 9 r1            328             3
10 r2            330             1
# ... with 17 more rows
```

I thought to use the `group_by(individuals)` and `mutate(period_number =)`functions from `dplyr`, but I can't figure out which function to use inside `mutate()`. I tried to look from several other questions here ([Condtionally create new columns based on specific numeric values (keys) from existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666823/condtionally-create-new-columns-based-on-specific-numeric-values-keys-from-exi), [How to add column into a dataframe based on condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016723/how-to-add-column-into-a-dataframe-based-on-condition)), but as the numbers in the group column are not categories but just running id numbers for different periods, I don't think I can use them with e.g. `if_else()`.

I'm sure there must be a rather simple solution for this, but I simply can't seem to be able to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `dense_rank` : `myData %>%
  group_by(individuals) %>%
  mutate(period_number = dense_rank(group))
`

Comment: @RonakShah That did it! Thank you so much!